# How to override core history_cron

Tags: 8, hooks, cron

I want to display the reading history of nodes using Views.
For this reason there is a history module in core, but the [history_cron](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21history%21history.module/function/history_cron/8.8.x)  hook deletes history older than 1 month.
I want to override this hook so that history is not deleted.
What should i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A module can avoid Drupal invokes a hook defined from another module, implementing [`hook_module_implements_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/8.9.x). For example, a module using  history_ovverrides as machine name could use the following implementation of that hook.

```
function history_overrides_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'cron') {
    // Remove history_cron() from the list of the hook_cron() implementations.
    unset($implementations['history']);
  }
}
```

The same module could implement `hook_cron()` to delete the History module data basing on different criteria (for example, after 6 months).

Answer (score 3):

With [Ultimate Cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron) you can problably disable it from running using its configuration form.

If you look at its [API](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/ultimate_cron/-/blob/8.x-2.x/ultimate_cron.api.php), it adds a hook_cron_alter that you could implement if you wanted to do it by code.